# Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, sendmail

HI I Am Trying to send email From Laravel, Env Is set To

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=base64:LgB1943ksdzDoHtwq47NsOn8ALDAs61WJkLEmCxo7Rg=
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=taniscart
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=......@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=.....
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

'Mial.php' Also same value, When I am trying send main I have following Error

```
Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. 16sm51877462pfy.4 - gsmtp[Error][1]
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and it disappeared one I added the "MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls"